# Leaftlet react javascript. use state to zoom in on map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I'm completely new to programming and leaflet and now I'm stuck.

my code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from "react-leaflet";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import L from "leaflet";

function App() {
  const markerIcon = new L.Icon({
    iconUrl:
      "https://cdn.rawgit.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-green.png", //change icon color to grey
    iconSize: [25, 41],
    iconAnchor: [12, 41],
    popupAnchor: [1, -34],
    shadowUrl:
      "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
    shadowSize: [41, 41],
  });

  const [countryList, setCountryList] = useState(null);
  const [filteredCountries, setFilteredCountries] = useState(null); // add a new state to store the filtered list
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState([51.505, -0.09]);
  console.log(typeof mapCenter);
  const [mapZoom, setMapZoom] = useState(3);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setCountryList(data);
        setFilteredCountries(data); // set the initial value of filteredCountries to be equal to countryList
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log("Error:", err));
  }, []);
  function filterItems(countryList, query) {
    return countryList.filter(
      (el) => el.name.common.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase()) //filters out the names from the fetch API into a new function
    );
  }

  function zoomCountryMap(latlng) {
    //function to zoom in on selected country
    console.log("zoomCountryMap called with latlng:", latlng);
    setMapCenter([latlng[0], latlng[1]]);
    setMapZoom(5);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by country..."
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          padding: "0.5em",
          paddingLeft: "1.5em",
          fontSize: "16px",
        }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFilteredCountries(filterItems(countryList, e.target.value));
          console.log(filterItems(countryList, e.target.value));
        }}
      />

      <div style={{ height: "100vh", width: "700px", overflow: "scroll" }}>
        <table id="country">
          <thead>
            <tr className="sticky-heading">
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Country
              </th>
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Capital
              </th>
              <th className="table-cell" style={{ width: "200px" }}>
                Region
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {filteredCountries ? ( // check if filteredCountryList is not null
              filteredCountries.map(
                (
                  table // iterate over the filtered list
                ) => (
                  <tr key={table.name.common}>
                    <td>{table.name.common}</td>
                    <td>{table.capital}</td>
                    <td>{table.region}</td>
                    <td>
                      <button onClick={() => zoomCountryMap(table.latlng)}>
                        Zoom
                      </button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )
              )
            ) : (
              <tr>
                <td colSpan="3">Search for country...</td>
              </tr>
            )}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <MapContainer
        center={mapCenter}
        zoom={mapZoom}
        scrollWheelZoom={false}
        onClick={() => console.log("MapContainer clicked")}
      >
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
        />

        {countryList &&
          countryList.map((markers) => (
            <Marker
              key={markers.name.common}
              position={[markers.latlng[0], markers.latlng[1]]}
              icon={markerIcon}
            >
              <Popup>
                <h1> {markers.name.common} </h1>
                <h3>
                  <p> Capital: {markers.capital}</p>
                  <p> Region: {markers.region}</p>
                  <p> Subregion: {markers.subregion}</p>
                  <p>
                    {" "}
                    Currencies:{" "}
                    {Object.keys(markers.currencies ?? {}) // looping trough all currencies, then getting name from    object in value

                      .map((key) => markers.currencies[key]["name"])
                      .join(", ")}{" "}
                  </p>
                </h3>
              </Popup>
            </Marker>
          ))}
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my problem is that when I'm triggering zoomCountryMap i get the coordinates, but the states doesn't work (

```
  setMapCenter([latlng[0], latlng[1]]);
    setMapZoom(5);
```

)

I'm passing the states to the props of the mapcontainer, but it won't work :( I can prolly write the whole app "cleaner" but for now, I rather not and just want to learn what is going on.

```css
.leaflet-container {
  width: 80vw;
  height: 100vh;

  background-color: #faf9f6;
}

.leaflet-layer {
  top: 0;
}
.App {
  height: 100vh;

  display: flex;
  background-color: #2b3035;

  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

input {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
p {
  line-height: 14px;
}

td :hover {
  background-color: grey;
}
h1 {
  color: grey;
}

.leaflet-bar > a:link {
  color: grey;
}
.sticky-heading {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #2b3035;
  width: 700px;
}
table {
  border-collapse: separate;

  border-color: grey;
  text-align: center;

  font-family: "Poppins", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #343a40;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [`MapContainer` documentation](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/) it states

> Except for its `children`, `MapContainer` props are **immutable**: changing them after they have been set a first time will have no effect on the Map instance or its container.

---

So you will have to use [`useMap`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#usemap) to get the instance of the map, and then call the api methods of leaflet, to interact with the map. In your case the `setView` which accepts both the center and zoom level.

```
const map = useMap();
```

and

```
function zoomCountryMap(latlng) {
  //function to zoom in on selected country
  console.log("zoomCountryMap called with latlng:", latlng);
  map.setView([latlng[0], latlng[1]], 5);
}
```

But since, the `useMap` must be called by a descendant of the `MapContainer` you will have extract the `MapContainer` to be higher in the hierarchy.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `whenReady` event and get the `map` instance from there and store it in state for calling the leaflet API.

so

```
const [mapRef, setMapRef] = useState(null);
```

and then

```
  <MapContainer
    ...
    whenReady={({ target }) => setMapRef(target)}
  >
```

now you can use `mapRef.setView(latlng, zoomlevel)`

Comment: thank you so much, I learn something new everyday!

Comment: So I need to rewrite the states too to get it to work? I don't get exactly "higher in the hierachy". I need the mapcontainer further up in the code?

Comment: The `useMap` needs to be in a component that is rendered as a child of the  `MapContainer`

Comment: I got the first part, but I bit unsure about the usemap vs mapcontainer

Comment: @Brede can you please add the css at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-https-mq3dbr?file=/src/App.css) file, then save and post the link here ? So i can suggest how to do it, without breaking other stuff.

Comment: I'm a newbie right now, so the css is a mess, but here.

Comment: @Brede i think you forgot the link :)

Comment: lol i didnt see the link; https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-shockley-d3zecc

Comment: I also have this css an js from leaflet.

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"
      integrity="sha256-kLaT2GOSpHechhsozzB+flnD+zUyjE2LlfWPgU04xyI="
      crossorigin=""
    />
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"
      integrity="sha256-WBkoXOwTeyKclOHuWtc+i2uENFpDZ9YPdf5Hf+D7ewM="
      crossorigin=""
    ></script>

as i only used a example from leaftlet rather then building it from scratch, in lacking of knowledge.

Comment: Ok, i used a different approach because the `useMap` is a bit hard to use in your setup. I used the `whenReady` event and stored the `map` reference in state. The again you can use this to call the leaflet api. Example at https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-https-mq3dbr?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thanks :)! i will have a look and try to see if I understand it! Im starting as a front end dev early next year and this is my first "real" task from my new boss, so much to learn! thanks again.

Comment: Exactly what does whenReady do? wait for a render before changing?

Comment: @Brede it is an event fired when the map is initialized. See https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-whenready

Comment: I'm struggling a bit to see why I can't access the data from the API in the zoom function, like I do further down the code. Is that the structure of javascript/hierarchy? I want a popup to click when zoomed, that shoukld display the same data as the code do now for all the markers.

Comment: @Brede You can access the API data anywhere in the component. To open the popup when you click on the buttons in your list, you need to store a [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) to the marker, and then call the `openPopup` method of it to open the popup. I believe you should create a new question for this.